# display current user data in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In MVC i want to authenticate users,they must not be able to see other user data when logged on. Users must be able to CRUD their own data only. I have created two model:

```
public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}


public class Product
{
    public int productId { get; set; }
    public string productName { get; set; }
    public double productPrice { get; set; }

    public User Users { get; set; }
}
```

And i have product controller, where i want to authenticate users from CRUD other users data.

Comment: This site is for answering specific questions, ideally once you've given it a shot. Google asp mvc tutorials if you have no idea where to start. You should find some info.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your code to perform CRUD operations on only the products available for logged in user.
Use below scenario for your requirement.

```
public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Products { 
        get{ 
            //get all products from database/storage for this user. for ex: I have called a method to get products
            //you can filter products related to this user by sending this user id to database or using code like below
            //Writing this code/logic in controller would be preferable

            return GetAllProducts().Where(p => p.Users.id == this.id).ToList();
        }
        set; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with **Rajesh**, I would recommend you use **Current User's data** and filter Rajesh you showed. Current User's Data may include Id of current logged user. If you use cookies to keep user's session, you can retrieve his Id from cookies in controller or filter attribute: `HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["auth_cookie"]`.